# How to navigate from UITableViewCell to UICollectionViewController programmatically in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Here is what I want to achieve: When I tap a UITabViewCell (Picture 1), it will navigate to an UICollectionViewController (Picture 2). Just like the following two pictures showing:

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

I could navigate to an UIViewController when tap a UITableViewCell, but it doesn't work when I try to navigate to UICollectionView. Here are my codes:

```
import UIKit

class RealUserProfileController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    private let me = ["Vincent-St"]
    private let followers = ["58 Followers"]
    private let myPhotos = ["New Followers"]
    private let others = ["My likes", "Notifications", "Clear Caches", "Drafts"]
    private let settings = ["Settings"]
    private let share = ["Share with friends"]
    private let images = ["Hearts.png", "Footprint.png", "Notifications.png", "Trash-Empty.png"]


    private let sections = ["me", "myPhotos", "others", "settings", "share"]



    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18)!, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
        navigationItem.title = "Profile"
        let displayWidth: CGFloat = self.view.frame.width
        let displayHeight: CGFloat = self.view.frame.height
        let myTableView: UITableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: displayWidth, height: displayHeight), style: .grouped)


        myTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")

        myTableView.dataSource = self

        myTableView.delegate = self

        self.view.addSubview(myTableView)

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.95)

        myTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        myTableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        myTableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        myTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            return 72
        }
        return tableView.rowHeight
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let controller = UserProfileController()
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
             print("Value: \(me[indexPath.row])")
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            print("Value: \(myPhotos[indexPath.row])")
        } else if indexPath.section == 2 {
            print("Value: \(others[indexPath.row])")
        } else if indexPath.section == 3 {
            let controller = ResultController()
            navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
            print("Value: \(settings[indexPath.row])")
        } else if indexPath.section == 4 {
            print("Value: \(share[indexPath.row])")
            let shareText = "Share our app"
            let shareImage = UIImage(named: "bell_unselected.png")
            let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText, shareImage as Any], applicationActivities: nil)
            self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }



    // return the number of cells each section.
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return me.count
        } else if section == 1 {
            return myPhotos.count
        } else if section == 2 {
            return others.count
        } else if section == 3 {
            return settings.count
        } else if section == 4 {
            return share.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    // return cells

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        if indexPath.section == 0 {

            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(me[indexPath.row])"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(followers[indexPath.row])"
            cell.imageView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile_image")

        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(myPhotos[indexPath.row])"
            cell.imageView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_friends")
        } else if indexPath.section == 2 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(others[indexPath.row])"
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(named: images[indexPath.row])

        } else if indexPath.section == 3 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(settings[indexPath.row])"
            cell.imageView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Icon_Settings")
        } else if indexPath.section == 4 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(share[indexPath.row])"
            cell.imageView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Share")
        }

        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator

        return cell
    }

}
```

The two lines of codes will crash the app:

```
       let controller = UserProfileController()
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Here is the error message:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'UserProfileController.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'
```

Here are the codes of the destination UICollectionViewController:

```
class UserProfileController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout  {

}
```

After some research, I didn't find any useful information. Is there any way to make it happen? Or is there any way to implement the Picture 2 in another way, maybe: UIViewController, instead of UICollectionView?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to make viewController From storyboard

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @YunCHEN there is no error message, just crash.

Comment: @user174782 you should navigate to UIViewController only because it has collection view as subview. If controller is in storyboard , give destination controller an identifier and then instantiate it with identifier, and perform push.

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani Unfortunately, Storyboard is not considered.

Comment: which line exactly is the source of crash?

Comment: Try add `Exception Breakpoint` to locate the crash position.

Comment: This two lines will crash the app:       let controller = UserProfileController()
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

Comment: try to create a simple `UIViewController` instead of `UserProfileController` to see if it happens in such a case too

Comment: @MilanNosáľ A simple UIViewController works well when a cell taped.

Comment: can you post the code for `UserProfileController`

Comment: Show the crash log. "unwrap nil found" I guess? If you use Xib (at least), and you have IBOutlet connected to it, using `let controller = UserProfileController()` "won't call the ViewController Linked with xib".

Comment: @TusharSharma Thank you, sir. I’m just no sure if it only can navigate to a UIViewController. If it can only navigate to an UIViewController, I may have to rewrite the user profile page.

Comment: do you have any code in`UserProfileController`?

Comment: @Larme , here is the error message: Cannot convert value of type 'UserProfileController.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

Comment: @ Yun CHEN here is the error message: Cannot convert value of type 'UserProfileController.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with navigation, any subclass of `UIViewController` should be navigable.

I believe you need to initialize `UICollectionViewController` using `init(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout)`, `collectionView` has to have the layout set, otherwise the `collectionView` will crash if it gets presented.

Therefore instead of:

```
let controller = UserProfileController()
```

try using:

```
let controller = UserProfileController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
```

Here I am assuming that the following code is your full implementation of `UserProfileController`, thus you directly inherit initializers from `UICollectionViewController`:

```
class UserProfileController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout  {

}
```

Comment: Oh, man. That's where the problem. Thank you so much. You saved me.

Comment: I fell into this trap several times already too.. thanks for the upvote